# ControlsCollection WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to make a ControlsCollection in WPF. In Wondow Forms we have 'this.ControlsCollection' and I want the same thing in WPF application.
I have a window with grids,stack panels,buttons,........
And I want to make a collection of all these controls, can anyone tell me how can i do it please...?

Comment: What is wrong with `this.Children` from within the control?

Comment: Please, edit your own question, don't post answers unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Could we have a small code sample? Think it would make this question a lot clearer with regards to your "first panel only" issue

Answer (score 0):

WPF controls usually use [`UIElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx), but for your own controls you can use any collection that implements [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx). If you want a generic collection, [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) works just fine.